# Is there a way to populate and use a variable directly from disk in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

For example:

```
var myIndex = populateMassiveIndex();
```

In the code above, let's assume `myIndex` would take up huge amounts of memory.... way more than is available. Is there a way in C# where I can bypass memory and populate and access a variable directly to and from disk instead, even though it may be much slower?

Specifically BEFORE the variable is loaded with data so when I assign values it goes directly to disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot directly use disk to back a variable, but you can allow the operating system to do that for you.  That's how [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) works.

However, I suspect you may find [memory mapped files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to be far better suited to what you are actually trying to accomplish.

> A memory-mapped file contains the contents of a file in virtual memory. This mapping between a file and memory space enables an application, including multiple processes, to modify the file by reading and writing directly to the memory. Starting with the .NET Framework 4, you can use managed code to access memory-mapped files in the same way that native Windows functions access memory-mapped files, as described in Managing Memory-Mapped Files in Win32 in the MSDN Library.